# Adding elements to form dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to add elements when a button is clicked, my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form-one">
        <button onclick="addChargingSchedule()">Add</button>
        <div class="cs"></div>
    </form>
</center>

<script>
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cs");

    function addChargingSchedule() {
        var form = document.getElementById("form-one")
        var id = document.createElement("input");
        
        id.setAttribute("type", "text");
        id.setAttribute("name", "one");
        id.setAttribute("id", "one");
        id.setAttribute("placeholder", "1");
        
        form.appendChild(id)
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works, when I click on the button, an input text is created but after like 0.1 secondes, the page is refreshed and the input disapears again.
Someone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to stop form submission.

Comment: @Spectric and how can I do that?

Comment: Set the button's `type` attribute to `button`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `submit` event listener and stop it like this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Working example taken by your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form-one">
        <button onclick="addChargingSchedule()">Add</button>
        <div class="cs"></div>
    </form>
</center>

<script>
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cs");
 var form = document.getElementById("form-one")
    function addChargingSchedule() {
       
        var id = document.createElement("input");
        
        id.setAttribute("type", "text");
        id.setAttribute("name", "one");
        id.setAttribute("id", "one");
        id.setAttribute("placeholder", "1");
        
        form.appendChild(id);
    }
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```